# SQL Server 2016 ISNULL Returning 1900-01-01

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a `datetime2` column called `DocDate` that I am trying to evaluate an `ISNULL` check against to return a blank `''` value for instead of `NULL`.

A snippet of the statement:

```
SELECT TOP 100
    DocumentId
    ,DocDate
    ,ISNULL(DocDate,'') AS 'DocDateEmpty'
FROM
    DocDetails
WHERE
    DocDate IS NULL
```

This returns: `1900-01-01 00:00:00.0000000`

My `WHERE` clause clearly brings back only the rows that are explicitly `NULL`, so it is not an issue of `DocDate` being an empty string and evaluating to `0`.

[image: SSMS Capture]

How can `DocDate IS NULL` evaluate correctly but `ISNULL` fails?

Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx), `ISNULL` should evaluate the **literal** `NULL` value correctly and return an empty value.

> Returns the same type as *check_expression*. If a literal NULL is provided as *check_expression*, returns the datatype of the *replacement_value*. If a literal NULL is provided as *check_expression* and no *replacement_value* is provided, returns an **int**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will happen with `DATETIME` as well as `DATETIME2`:

```
DECLARE @dummy DATETIME2 = NULL
SELECT @dummy, ISNULL(@dummy, N'')
GO 

DECLARE @dummy DATETIME = NULL
SELECT @dummy, ISNULL(@dummy, N'')
GO
```

Along with `DATE` and `TIME`

```
DECLARE @dummy DATE = NULL
SELECT @dummy, ISNULL(@dummy, N'')
GO 

DECLARE @dummy TIME = NULL
SELECT @dummy, ISNULL(@dummy, N'')
GO
```

I think the easiest way around it is to add a second `CONVERT` to a string:

```
DECLARE @dummy DATETIME2 = NULL
SELECT @dummy, ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), @dummy), N'')
GO
```

Which returns an empty string as desired.

To answer your question about *why*, well, let's look at another scenario:

```
DECLARE @dummy INT = NULL 
SELECT @dummy, ISNULL(@dummy, '')
```

The `ISNULL` here returns 0. If you're not up on how SQL Server stores and deals with dates, see my [Q&A here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187694/how-does-date-math-work-in-sql-server) for more information.

In short, if you run `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 0)`, you get a familiar result. There's no such thing as an empty number, and there's no conversion of an empty string to a numeric expression.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @sp_BitzErik Thank you. I was hoping I could avoid having to write a bunch of `CONVERT` statements (DocDate is just one of many columns to be transformed), but it appears I'll have to bite the bullet. The behavior seems odd given that the documentation is somewhat misleading. In my mind, their statement: `If a literal NULL is provided as check_expression, returns the datatype of the replacement_value.` Since my `replacement_value` of `''` is a string, I would assume I could return an empty string. Do you have any knowledge on why this behavior exists for `date` data types?

Comment: FYI - The reason for this is implicit data conversion.

IsNull takes its output data type from the first parameter, which in this case is a DateTime.

When the value is null, you are substituting an empty string value, which is then implicitly converted to a date time. Since it is an empty string, it is converted internally to a zero, which equates to the date 1900-01-01.

This is why the solution requires another Convert statement to work around the issue.

Comment: @PicoDeGallo updated answer.